# Saving state in Gmail addons

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I want to be able to save state in my Gmail addon.
Is it possible? something like a cookie or the like.
(For the purpose of authenticating the user)

Thank you

Comment: PropertiesService? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

Comment: Thanks @AntonDementiev, you can write it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Glad I could help - added this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use PropertiesService to persist data in Google Apps Script

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/